# .xsession and startx in debian

Tags: debian, xorg, startx

If my homefolder doesn't have a `.xinitrc` but has a `.xsession` consists of:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
exec jwm
```

Will `startx -- -nolisten local -nolisten tcp` actually process the `-nolisten` options?

I think if I create a `.xinitrc` with the same content, `startx` won't process any option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startx` will split its command line arguments into two groups, separated by the double dash: the X client to start (+ its arguments), and the X server options.

Supplying a `.xinitrc` is one way to provide a user-specific default for the X client part; it should have no effect at all on the X server options part. If it actually does have an effect, that would be a bug.

In Debian 10, if the user has no `.startxrc` and no `.xinitrc`, and the system administrator has not created a system-wide `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys.startxrc` (or whichever path is appropriate for your hardware architecture - it does not exist by default anyway), then `startx` will use `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` as the X client part.

By default, this will just source the X11 session script `/etc/X11/Xsession`, which should be universal to all X session startup methods in Debian. It will in turn source any scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` directory. Among those, `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50x11-common_determine-startup` will detect the presence of user's `.xsession` file, and later `99x11-common_start` will execute it with `exec`, once all the other `Xsession.d` scripts have been run.

---

But if you use both `-nolisten local` and `-nolisten tcp` server options, will there be any X11 transport methods left usable? According to the `X(7)` man page, if the `DISPLAY` variable has an empty string as the host specification, for example with the default DISPLAY value of `:0` or `:0.0` for the local session, the `local` transport method would be used. If it has been disabled, I would expect the session to inevitably fail - but I have not investigated this corner of the X11 session startup in any sort of detail since very long ago, so I might be missing something.